# What programming language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

We're trying to script a CAD program, and this is the example for controlling the date in our design slugs, but I don't even know what language it is to know what to do with it.

```
! LIBEDATE

def &d$ &ret$

set &d$ = rstr(`/`,` `,#d$);
set &ret$ = word(&d$,2),`/`,word(&d$,1),`/`,subs(word(&d$,3), -2, 2)
```

Comment: What CAD program are you using? It may be a custom scripting language designed specifically for that program.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems to be a DSL. An easy to parse one at that. You can tell due to the different variable things like `&var$`

Comment: Aren't DSLs characterized by providing primitives to work with domain objects? The code there just does some string processing which wouldn't be too typical an application for a DSL.

Comment: @Johannes, usually, but they may have tried to make it more like a regular language (and failed) when designing it.

Comment: looks like "libedate" is an estonian word that means "slippery". I am sure this helped a lot!

Comment: @Eugene: but then again it could be the library for edate.

Comment: @Hutch: I think you stumped SO!  You should get a badge for that.

Answer (score 1):

What CAD is it? Almost all the ancient CADs have their own (typically weird and ill-designed) scripting languages. Can it be one of the Tribon products?

Answer (score 0):

It might be [AutoCAD Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoLISP)

Comment: Lisp wouldn't have a `def` and `set` function would it? Also there isn't nearly enough parentheses..

Comment: doesn't look like lisp to me, either.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be Tcl, but I don't any more... sorry (and thanks Johannes).

Comment: Tcl doesn't use parentheses for command arguments. Neither has the `=` sign any relevance.

Comment: yes, definetly to many perlesque symbols to be vanilla TCL too - though technically you could probably write this DSL in TCL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be some kind of macro language maybe? Lua or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Would it be Python?

Comment: Don't think so. Python `def`s are followed by colons and the ! LIBEDATE doesn't make sense, either.

Comment: @Evgeny I believe "LIBEDATE" is actually a comment. Google tells me it means "driving" in Estonian.